# Software defined system

Tags: ethernet, packet-analysis, sdn, openflow

Over (Software defined network) what will happen when unknown Ethernet hits the first switch, using 4 OF switch and 8 host.

Comment: [off in the weeds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225595/whats-the-origin-of-the-phrase-into-the-weeds)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If by Ethernet, you mean Ethernet 'frames' then that packet is sent to the Controller. The Controller then instructs the Switch about packet modification and actions for output port.
Alternatively, the Switch may just send a 'pointer' to the packet rather than sending the whole packet to the Controller.